# Data corruption mysql with openssl

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, openssl, corruption

I use openssl to encrypt a text, then put this into a mysql database.
This works fine, however with long texts, the decrypted text becomes corrupted.

Personally I think this is due to the way mysql saves this text into the database, there are a lot of not alpha numeric characters in the encrypted text. But I am not sure about that.
Also I don't know which collation to use in mysql, right now I set it to *utf8_unicode_ci*, but still there is corruption of data.

A live example can be seen here: http://todolist.x10.mx

```
Username: example
Password: password
```

To view the corrupted data, click `Download Backup`.

Below the code, of course `$encrypted` is saved into the database. This code works fine without database.

```
<?php
  $source = 'very long text';
  $iv = "1234567812345678";
  $pass = 'difficultpassphrase';
  $method = 'aes-256-ofb';

  $encrypted = openssl_encrypt ($source, $method, $pass, true, $iv);  
  echo $encrypted;

  $decrypted = openssl_decrypt ($encrypted, $method, $pass, true, $iv);
  echo $decrypted;
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

To store encrypted content in binary form, you can't use a character type with encoding since it's very likely that the encoding "breaks" your data.

You should instead use [BINARY or VARBINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) datatypes, they're made exactly for the purpose of storing binary data.

The alternative is to [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the data before storing it in the character datatypes, and [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) the data when you've fetched it from the database. This will encode the data so that the encrypted data is possible to store in a varchar/char datatype (although it will make the data slightly longer, so beware of that)

Comment: I use base64_encode/decode as you mentioned, however the problem still persists. Very smart idea though.
I use mysql_real_escape_string on top of base64_encode, maybe this is causing trauble? Which I think is not very likely.
    mysql_real_escape_string(base64_encode($encrypted))

And by setting the field to binary or varbinary the field length automatically becomes 1, when I try to make it bigger I receive an error.
I set it back to blob

Comment: I found the problem: I performed a stripslashes() before showing the note.